# HTML: grouping input fields

Tags: html

I have many input fields with `type="text"`

```
<input type="text" id="...">
<input type="text" id="...">
<input type="text" id="...">
...
<input type="text" id="...">
<input type="text" id="...">
<input type="text" id="...">
```

I want to prevent from typing `type="text"` on every input. Is there any way to group inputs like this:

```
<inputgroup type="text">
   <input id="...">
   <input id="...">
   <input id="...">
</inputgroup>
```

The solution can be coded with HTML, Javascript or anything else for WEB.

Comment: do you want to remove all type attribute?

Comment: No need for script, simply omit the type ... as Quentin already answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use JavaScript/jQuery to achieve what you are looking for. Here is the **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/knnx3dvp/)** for what you are looking for.

```
    <!--Group all your input fields within a 'div' and give this div a unique ID-->
    <div id="inputGroupText">
      <input id='a' />
      <input id='b' />
      <input id='c' />
    </div>

<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
          //iterate through the div which groups all the 'input' fields
          $('#inpuGroupText').children('input').each(function () {
               // you can substitute 'text' with 'email', 'password' etc. depending on your need
               $(this).attr('type', 'text');
          });
     });
</script>
```

Note: If you just want to avoid writing `type='text'` then you can just ignore it because 'text' is the default value for 'type' attribute so if the browser will automatically consider the input field as `type=text` if you have not specified value for it.

Comment: Thank you, I will use your solution! @Saumil Soni

Comment: @BrenGinthom Glad could help.

Answer (score 2):

No.

There is a way to group inputs: `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` but that is for grouping them based on what is going to be entered into them (such as for when you have multiple fields making up the different parts of an address).

There is no way, in HTML, to set the type attribute other than explicitly.

That said, `type="text"` is the **default**, so you can simply omit the attribute entirely (unless you depend on it for other reasons, such as with a CSS attribute selector).

---

You could also generate the HTML programmatically (e.g. with a template language).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a javascript function to dynamically inject input tags inside a div

```
(function(){
var inject='';
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    inject+="<input type='text' value='"+i+"' id='id_"+i+"'/><br/>"
}
$('#inject').html(inject);

})();


<div id="inject">
//input tags will be injected here after function execution
</div>
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/abk0hvts/

Comment: If this solved your problem then choose it as Correct Answer to help others in future.

Answer (score -1):

Same solution but the code is much more readable :)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var parent = document.getElementById('autobot');
      var tags = parent.getElementsByTagName('input');
      for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        tags[i].setAttribute('type', 'text');
      }
    });
</script>

<div id="autobot">        
    <input>
    <input>
    <input>
  </div>
```